# Code Inspection: Procedure not used

Tags: c#, performance, linq, antlr, rubberduck

Here is yet another piece of [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com) code, this time the nasty `ProcedureNotUsedInspection` class, whose role is to identify all procedures that are never called anywhere, and to issue a `ProcedureNotUsedInspectionResult` for each one.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Rubberduck.Parsing;
using Rubberduck.Parsing.Grammar;
using Rubberduck.Parsing.Symbols;

namespace Rubberduck.Inspections
{
    public class ProcedureNotUsedInspection : IInspection
    {
        public ProcedureNotUsedInspection()
        {
            Severity = CodeInspectionSeverity.Hint;
        }

        public string Name { get { return InspectionNames.ProcedureNotUsed_; } }
        public CodeInspectionType InspectionType { get { return CodeInspectionType.CodeQualityIssues; } }
        public CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultBase> GetInspectionResults(VBProjectParseResult parseResult)
        {
            var handlers = parseResult.Declarations.Items.Where(item => item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Control)
                .SelectMany(control => parseResult.Declarations.FindEventHandlers(control));

            var issues = parseResult.Declarations.Items
                .Where(item => !IsIgnoredProcedure(parseResult.Declarations, item, handlers))
                .Select(issue => new IdentifierNotUsedInspectionResult(string.Format(Name, issue.IdentifierName), Severity, issue.Context, issue.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName));

            return issues;
        }

        private bool IsIgnoredProcedure(Declarations declarations, Declaration declaration, IEnumerable<Declaration> handlers)
        {
            var result = 
                declaration.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Procedure
                || handlers.Contains(declaration)
                || declaration.References.Any()
                || IsPublicModuleMember(declarations, declaration)
                || IsClassLifeCycleHandler(declarations, declaration)
                || IsInterfaceMember(declarations, declaration);

            return result;
        }

        /// <remarks>
        /// We cannot determine whether exposed members of standard modules are called or not,
        /// so we assume they are instead of flagging them as "never called".
        /// </remarks>
        private bool IsPublicModuleMember(Declarations declarations, Declaration procedure)
        {
            var parent = declarations.Items.SingleOrDefault(item =>
                        item.IdentifierName == procedure.ComponentName &&
                        (item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Module));

            return parent != null && (procedure.Accessibility == Accessibility.Implicit
                                      || procedure.Accessibility == Accessibility.Public);
        }

        private static readonly string[] ClassLifeCycleHandlers =
        {
            "Class_Initialize",
            "Class_Terminate"
        };

        private bool IsClassLifeCycleHandler(Declarations declarations, Declaration procedure)
        {
            var parent = declarations.Items.SingleOrDefault(item =>
                        item.IdentifierName == procedure.ComponentName &&
                        (item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Class));

            return parent != null && ClassLifeCycleHandlers.Contains(procedure.IdentifierName);
        }

        /// <remarks>
        /// Interface implementation members are private, they're not called from an object
        /// variable reference of the type of the procedure's class, and whether they're called or not,
        /// they have to be implemented anyway, so removing them would break the code.
        /// Best just ignore them.
        /// </remarks>
        private bool IsInterfaceMember(Declarations declarations, Declaration procedure)
        {
            // get the procedure's parent module
            var parent = declarations.Items.SingleOrDefault(item =>
                       item.IdentifierName == procedure.ComponentName &&
                       (item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Class));

            if (parent == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var classes = declarations.Items.Where(item => item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Class);
            var interfaces = classes.Where(item => item.References.Any(reference =>
                    reference.Context.Parent is VBAParser.ImplementsStmtContext));

            if (interfaces.Select(i => i.ComponentName).Contains(procedure.ComponentName))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // todo: find a way to avoid running this for every procedure in a class
            var result = GetImplementedInterfaceMembers(declarations, procedure.ComponentName)
                .Contains(procedure.IdentifierName);

            return result;
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetImplementedInterfaceMembers(Declarations declarations, string componentName)
        {
            var classes = declarations.Items.Where(item => item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Class);
            var interfaces = classes.Where(item => item.References.Any(reference =>
                    reference.Context.Parent is VBAParser.ImplementsStmtContext
                    && reference.QualifiedModuleName.ModuleName == componentName));

            var members = interfaces.SelectMany(declarations.FindMembers)
                .Select(member => member.ComponentName + "_" + member.IdentifierName);
            return members;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are a number of constraints and assumptions that we need to make here:

- Any `Public` procedure that can be called from Excel as a user-defined function or a "macro" is ignored, because we can't tell whether it's actually used or not.
- Event handlers and class life cycle handlers are called by VBA itself, so they're ignored too.
- An interface can only be recognized as such if it's implemented somewhere.

Now, the main issue I have is one of performance - I need to figure out a way to reorganize the code in this inspection so as to avoid doing redundant checks like I'm doing; I'd like this code to be as efficient as possible, and I know it isn't - there are redundancies with detecting interface members, and I'm "finding" interface members way too many times (a module's members aren't going to change between two iterations!).

How can I clean this up without breaking it?

Comment: Just to clarify, a `procedure` could be a sub or function?

Comment: This one is ignoring `Function` procs for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Some basic refactoring:

#### Make members static

you can make `IsIgnoredProcedure()`, `IsPublicModuleMember()`, `IsClassLifeCycleHandler()`, `IsInterfaceMember()` and `GetImplementedInterfaceMembers()` static since they do not use any instance info.  Alternatively, if each instance of `ProcedureNotUsedInspection` were to be immutable (i.e. determine the results at instantiation and generate a new one every time code changes) then you could make the declarations code a field.

Making the methods static isn't really a great refactoring but I find that when something is static the compiler helps me to think about when I am working with instance level or common level things.

#### Extract HasParent

I created a method called HasParent() since `IsPublicModuleMember()`, `IsClassLifeCycleHandler()` and `IsInterfaceMember()` run the same code to determine if the declaration has a parent (as far as I can see).  This simplifies those methods also because there is no need to pass in the declarations.

```
    private static bool IsIgnoredProcedure(Declarations declarations, Declaration declaration, IEnumerable<Declaration> handlers)
    {
        var result = !ProcedureTypes.Contains(declaration.DeclarationType)
            || declaration.References.Any()
            || handlers.Contains(declaration)
            || HasParent(declarations, declaration)
            || IsPublicModuleMember(declaration)
            || IsClassLifeCycleHandler(declaration)
            || IsInterfaceMember(declarations, declaration);

        return result;
    }

    private static bool HasParent(Declarations declarations, Declaration procedure)
    {
        var parent = declarations.Items.SingleOrDefault(item =>
                     item.Project == procedure.Project &&
                     item.IdentifierName == procedure.ComponentName &&
                     item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Module);

        return parent != null;
    }

    /// <remarks>
    /// We cannot determine whether exposed members of standard modules are called or not,
    /// so we assume they are instead of flagging them as "never called".
    /// </remarks>
    private static bool IsPublicModuleMember(Declaration procedure)
    {
        return procedure.Accessibility == Accessibility.Implicit
            || procedure.Accessibility == Accessibility.Public;
    }

    private static readonly string[] ClassLifeCycleHandlers =
    {
        "Class_Initialize",
        "Class_Terminate"
    };

    private static bool IsClassLifeCycleHandler(Declaration procedure)
    {
        return ClassLifeCycleHandlers.Contains(procedure.IdentifierName);
    }
```

#### Recommend extract methods

I would also suggest that you create some method (or access a property) that provides the classes and interfaces that are declared.  Then you can call them from `IsInterfaceMember()`.  Surely these functions will be pretty commonly used, so they could be located elsewhere.

#### Question

I haven't used interfaces a lot in VBA, its a little cumbersome IMO.  So I'm not completely confident in this, but I have a question about the following in `IsInterfaceMember()`:

```
        if (interfaces.Select(i => i.ComponentName).Contains(procedure.ComponentName))
        {
            return true;
        }
```

This checks to see if there are any interface names in the name of the procedure, trying to match `Interface_Procedurename`.  But surely you would need to ensure that the declaration is inside a class and that class implements the interface (or can modules implement interfaces too)?

I think that you will need to separate the declarations into separate groups and work with them for the specific cases.  Can you work with classes/modules and then inspect their declarations?

Comment: To answer your question: indeed, that `IsInterfaceMember` code is pretty frail. [Fortunately a more robust way is coming up](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/GrammarIsFun/Rubberduck.Parsing/Symbols/Declarations.cs#L59-L87) :)